# Trying to figure out a spreadsheet equation to balance bills

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Basically I have a spreadsheet to show what has been paid by each member of a household on monthly bills, and I want it to show how much is owed to each other tenant, so that each has paid an equal share.

e.g. if tenant 1 pays $100, 2 pays $200 and 3 pays $300, tenant 1 would owe tenant 3 $100.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Edit: I've since made this question a lot clearer. I'm sorry if it was a little sloppy before :(

Edit: I have tried (((C:2 + C:3 + C:4) / 3) - C:4) which shows how much more tenant 3 has to pay, but now I need to split that between tenants 1 and 2 so that they have each paid $132.67

Comment: Let's **not** discuss. [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is not a dicussion forum. It is a Q&A site where you ask a **specific question** and receive **specific answers**. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Okay I removed the "let's discuss" part. Just trying to be light hearted. This is a pretty specific question.

Comment: so why not just subtract the average from the amount paid.  If it is positive that is the amount owed to the tenant and the negative is the amount to pay.

Comment: Thanks Scott, you're absolutely right that it would show how much is needed to pay, but I need to show how much to pay to each other tenant.

Comment: It will show that also: http://imgur.com/a/RzRmC

Comment: Hi Scott - see the updated question for what I'm after :)

Comment: Sorry Jeeped if you are after a fight I suggest you go elsewhere. I can't be more specific than this.

Comment: How do you know what tenant owes who? Should Tenant 3 pay $136 to both Tenant 1 and Tenant 3? The total paid so far is $398...is that the total? Does Tenant 1 owe Tenant 2 and 3 money too?  @Jeeped isn't looking for a fight, rather, he's looking for help from you. Just showing a table, and asking "how do I fill this in" isn't very helpful for us. I suggest reading through those links, and show us what you've tried. Right now, we can't see any effort from your side.

Comment: The tenants should all be paying an equal share of the overall bills. I'm sorry if I assumed that would be obvious based on 99% of all house shares.

Comment: Just showing a table, and asking "how do I fill this in" isn't very helpful for us. That's a wild exaggeration if there ever was one. What's with all the hate today?!

Comment: @OwainReed no hate, and if you went back through both Jeeped and BruseWaynes history you would see that they are two of the most calm people on the site.  But it is expected that you would show us what you have tried.  What formulas have you tried?  They are merely stating that Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.

Comment: OK Scott, I will try not to feel bullied then. I have updated the question with what I have so far and will update as I continue to look at the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your layout slightly so I can copy the formula down.

I am using Excel but it Should work in Google Sheets:

```
=IF(SIGN(VLOOKUP(A7,A:C,3,FALSE)-AVERAGE($C$2:$C$4))=-1,MIN(MAX(VLOOKUP(B7,A:C,3,FALSE)-AVERAGE($C$2:$C$4),0),AVERAGE($C$2:$C$4)-VLOOKUP(A7,A:C,3,FALSE)),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, that is a lot of formula! I'm just trying to figure out what you're doing and will get back to you.